# Using iText7 to Flatten XFA PDF

Tags: pdf

I'm looking for an example of the following:

1. Identifying whether a PDF is a XFA format
2. Reading the XFA fields and pulling the data
3. Flattening the XFA PDF
4. Rendering the Flattened PDF to a byte[] array image for database storage.

I accomplished this in `iTextSharp`, but it appears to be completely different in `iText7`.